# wp-paginate() showing blank page while navigating to other pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am using wp-paginate plugin for pagination on my wordpress site. The pagination links are showing fine. The problem is every page shows a blank page.
I am using following code to call pagination. I am new to wordpress so sorry for any mistakes..

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

      <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php //twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
            <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
        wp_paginate();
      }
      else {
        twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
      }
?>
```

Comment: You are using the `get_template_part` function. Do you really have the template `content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. There was a page named page.php on my server's root folder. I deleted it and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

You have stared if block but not close it. Enable errors you will get error in php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

      <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php //twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
            <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
        wp_paginate();
      }
      else {
        twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' );
      }
endif; //<--------------add end if
?>
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem. Pagination is working on localhost but not on server. Thanks for answer.